# How to automatically check for a new value in redis using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, redis

so I have two scripts : One that will pass data to redis and another one that will get the data from redis.

The script that will get the data from redis is written with node.js and the script that will send the data to redis is written in ruby.

I am looking for the rnode.js script to get the data from redis as soon as the ruby script sends it.

I was thinking about a continuous monitoring from node.js to check if there is an update into redis and as soon as there is an update , node.js grab the data. If you have a better way to do this , I'll consider it as well

I would like help clue about how should I write the node.js script to continuously monitor redis and grab any new data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is to use Redis' lists as queues.

Assuming that the Ruby script stores the new "data" under a key called `data:1`, have it also [`RPUSH`](https://redis.io/commands/rpush) the key's name to a list called `new_data` for example. This list is essentially a queue of all new data.

Now, have your 'rnode.js' script do a blocking left pop ([`BLPOP`](https://redis.io/commands/blpop)) on the `new_data` list. Whenever new data arrives, the script will unblock and you'll be able to process the news. Once finished, return to blocking pop.